# wordpress theme image behind footer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have my wordpress theme built but there is one problem, I want to have an image behind my footer but not be part of it. In my site I have my footer image that repeats horizontally and an image behind it which is a compass. My issue is when I put the image in it acts like part of the footer and not the background (it's not my background image just on top of it). Here is a link to my blog (the code is too long to post here):

http://blog.zombiesarefierce.com/

also here is a pic of what my footer is supposed to look like (the image i'm talking about is the compass), any help would be greatly appreciated:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/jq19y

Answer (score 0):

Just put your compass image in a new division and apply z-index to all elements at that point. Z-index specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. (Negative numbers are allowed)

[Check this link to know more about z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).